# How to show input the result from this multiply? React

Tags: reactjs

I have difficulty in multiplying the number with any number that I want and show result in the Stok column. I made a state that stores an object of each input as property {pcs: "", lusin:""}. And made a function that change target.value every time we change the input (onChange). And then what? I don't have no idea. I have difficulties in changing the data type from string to number it keeps showing as NaN in Stok column even after I parseInt

[image]

```
function UpdateStockModal(props) {
    const [inputLusin, setInputLusin] = useState(0);
    const [input, setInput] = useState({
        pcs: "",
        lusin: ""
    })

    const handleChange = e => {
        setInput(parseInt(e.target.value));
        console.log(totalPcsDariLusin, "< total")
        console.log(typeof totalPcsDariLusin, "tipe total");
        console.log('target value', typeof e.target.value);
    };

    let totalPcsDariLusin = 12 * parseInt(inputLusin)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(inputLusin)

    }, [input])

    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            className="modal"
            centered
        >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title className="modal-title">
                    Update stock
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <h4>Masukkan jumlah stok yang tersedia di rak saat ini.</h4>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>Kemasan</Col>
                        <Col>Jumlah</Col>
                        <Col>Stok</Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="modal-table-body">
                        <Col >Pcs</Col>
                        <Col className="d-flex align-items-center">1 x <Form.Control className="modal-input pcs" type="text" value={input.pcs} onChange={handleChange} /> = </Col>
                        <Col>{parseInt(input.pcs)}</Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="modal-table-body">
                        <Col>Lusin</Col>
                        <Col className="d-flex align-items-center">12 x <Form.Control className="modal-input lusin" type="text" value={input.lusin} onChange={handleChange} /> = </Col>
                        <Col>{input.lusin}</Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="modal-table-body">
                        <Col>Total Stok <span>(dalam pcs)</span></Col>
                        <Col>Lusin</Col>
                        <Col></Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={props.onHide}>Simpan</Button>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.onHide}>Batal</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
}

export default function PokemonDetail() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let { name } = useParams()

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <div className="pokemon-detail-page">
            <div className="pokemon-detail_button-group">
                <Button variant="outline-light" className="prev-button" onClick={() => {
                    navigate('/')
                }}><img src={prevPageIcon}></img>Stok Pokémon</Button>
                <Button className="update-stock-button" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>Update Stok</Button>
            </div>
            <p className="pokemon-detail-title" style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>{name}</p>
            <div className="pokemon-detail-subtitle">
                <p className="pokemon-detail-sub1">Sisa Stok</p>
                <p className="pokemon-detail-sub2">10 pcs</p>
            </div>
            <div className="pokemon-detail-history">
                <p className="pokemon-detail-history1">Riwayat Stok</p>
                <p className="pokemon-detail-history2">Satuan stok dalam pcs</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Table className="table row pokemon-detail-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="th-border ">
                            <th scope="col">Waktu</th>
                            <th scope="col">Kegiatan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Catatan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Jumlah</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stok</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className="align-items-center">
                            <td className="">2 Apr 2021, 08:00</td>
                            <td className="table-link">Update Stok</td>
                            <td className="">"Stok Awal"</td>
                            <td className="table-count-stock">+10</td>
                            <td className="table-bold">10</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>

            <UpdateStockModal
                show={modalShow}
                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
            />

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I was able to achieve this.

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

const App = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    pcs: "",
    lusin: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let newValue = {
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    };
    setInput(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Kemasan</th>
          <th>Jumlah</th>
          <th>Stok</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>pcs</td>
            <td>1 x</td>
            <td>
              <input
                name="pcs"
                value={input.pcs}
                type="number"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </td>
            <td>{input.pcs * 1}</td>
          </tr>

          {/*  */}
          <tr>
            <td>pcs</td>
            <td>12 x</td>
            <td>
              <input
                name="lusin"
                value={input.lusin}
                type="number"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </td>
            <td>{input.lusin * 12}</td>
          </tr>
          {/*  */}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Is this what your trying to achieve ?**